TexLive - changing repository to iso file or local folder
I have downloaded TexLive iso file (texlive-20240312) and done basic installation for book on windows 10. Now, I would like add a few packages to the installation from the local iso file. I am trying to change repository to the iso image mounted on the drive. When I changed the repository to the mounted drive, it says fail load. After closing this window, I have opened the manager and tried to selected the status of uninstalled packages. This opens an error message "back end gone" with the last command executed. The moment I click ok on the error message window, the manager closes.
I am interested to know the location of repository folder such that all the packages will be installed from the same local repository.
Update:
After looking in the documentation, I found the following in the documentation.

If the given argument is local (either a path or a file:/ url), compressed files in an archive subdirectory of the repository path are used (even if uncompressed files are available as well).

I have mounted the iso file and trying to provide the archive folder, which contains all the packages, as the repository path. The manager says that archives is not a repository!
I tried to update the repository using the command tlmgr update -all -dry-run. It ended with the following message.

tlmgr.pl: Remote database (revision 70581 of the texlive-scripts package) seems to be older than the local installation (rev 71250 of
texlive-scripts); please use a different mirror and/or wait a day or two.

I tried to change repository to different ctan mirror sites and then tried to add the local repository. Every time I got the same error messages like above in both gui and command window.

You cannot use the iso file directly as repository. But if you mount it resp. copy the content to a local directory you can select the tlnet sub-directory as repository.

@cabohah I am trying to choose the archive folder as repository, but it is not recognized by the manager!

Never tried it, but maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701507/36296 helps?

The manager does not accept iso file as repository!

Can you not install what you need from the online repos? Why use the iso particularly? I'm guessing - and it is only a guess - that you installed from online repos and not the iso. That's the most obvious way you'd end up with something newer installed. Alternatively, you updated TL after installing. Again, that would be using the online repos.

@cfr I may not have access to internet when I am in need. I would like to install on different systems. I dont want to waste data, when one could really save it. I will try to follow your instructions. Install latex keeping the system in offline mode and check whether the problem could be resolved. Thank you for your perspective.

Another option would be to avoid net installation but install the full scheme or similar. If you aren't short of disk space, that's by far the easiest option. In essence, that's what Overleaf does, although they may initially use online installation - not sure. But they don't update between releases unless something is really broken, so the package base and formats are frozen for each edition.

@cfr Thank you. Your perspective helped me to solve the problem. In the custom installation, there is an option, after install set CTAN as source for package updates. I have unchecked it in the offline installation. Now, It could install the packages from the local file repository.
